# Can I use Python for Android development?

Tags: java, android, python

Can I create simple programs for Android using Kivy or do I have to learn Java?

By simple, I mean some graphics (some rotating lines, a timer, a highscore), a memo etc not real-time games.

I've created this kind of programs for Windows/Linux and I'd really like to extend to Android.

On Google, most of the answers say that I should learn Java, whereas the remaining answers say that Python is pretty good. I also asked this question on chat, and some said 'yes', while others said 'no' and finally someone said "All programming languages get to be translated to JavaScript, so it is not much of a difference".

Comment: as per SO's rule, seeking library/tutorial etc. is off-topic. Your post is eligible for lot of downvote and may be removed soon! You may want to edit it and ask more specific Q

Comment: @AADTechnical It's not really that much about seeking library/tutorial, but it should be slightly changed into asking what are the benefits of using Kivy vs Java for Android development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. And may be Yes. Let me explain.

**No:**

- The app will not look native if you use Kivy
- There will be a lag in startup
- You can call native Java API using Pyjnius but sometimes it won't work fine or you will need to work very hard to get simple things done.
- Because you can not use the native UI, crafting a good looking android app might be a lot of work.

**Yes:**

- You can build an app that works
- Many games and apps don't use native UI but they are still very usable
- You can use projects like Plyer and Pyjnius to get the common android functionality
- Kivy might be an excellent choice for games

**My recommendation:**

Please do check out the apps and games built with Kivy on Play Store. Play with them on your phone or tab. See how they look and feel. Checkout the Kivy docs and see what they offer.

**PS:** I am a big time Python fan and I do like Kivy. I hope and believe that it will offer better widgets and UI integrations in the future. I wish Kivy offered something like NativeScript where I could use Python to create native widgets.